# Query string and Repeater

Tags: c#, query-string, repeater

i have a college project to build news website.In my homepage i have some links 
i am trying to pass query string thru this URL

`<a href="Content.aspx?Id=2&NewsId=6">`

MyContent.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Content.aspx.cs" Inherits="Content" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval ("NewsDetails") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind file

```
public partial class Content : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        int _NewsDetails = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["NewsDetails"]);
        int _NewsId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["NewsId"]);

        //open your database connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\MySite\\Pandheri\\App_Data\\Padheri.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select [NewsDetails],[Id] FROM Article",conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        adptr.Fill(ds);
        //close your database connection

        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
```

When i run the page i get all the data from NewsDetails table.

My database.

{News Table

Id,NewsCategory

Article Table

Id,NewsTitle,NewsDetails,NewsId}

Comment: And then? This isn't really question yet. A question mark must exist somewhere. I can't find it though. It's like Where's Waldo, except it's Where's Question Mark.

Comment: My query string is not working sir.can someone check my code?All the data from Newsdetails column is showing up.

Comment: Where are you using the query string values in the code? I can see you storing them in variables, but nothing afterwards.

Comment: NO. No concatenating the values! That is a practice you *must* learn to detest.

Comment: @OLDMONK - Here's a good article on how to debug and set up breakpoints http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming the `Id` and `NewsId` represent the `Id` and `NewsId` in the `Article` table respectively. You pass those values through the query string and want to pull the article related to those IDs from the database.

You're reading the query string fine. But you aren't doing anything with the values you are reading. You need to pass them to the SQL query. Your SqlCommand becomes:

```
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select [NewsDetails],[Id] FROM Article WHERE [Id]=@Id AND [NewsId]=@NewsId",conn);
```

Notice the `WHERE` clause. We are setting up parameters inside the SQL query. Now we need to fill those parameters with the values we got from the query string.

```
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", _Id);
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsId", _NewsId);
```

Now when the SqlCommand runs you should get *only* the article defined by those two IDs.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!! This has been my problem for the whole 2 weeks of my life. Our class project hasn't been approved because we dont know how to pass values from one page to another thank you so much sir.

Comment: @OLDMONK - No problem. Glad to be of help :)